# Redux's applyMiddleware cannot render middlewares

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to use  middleware in the following code

```
import { thunk } from 'redux-thunk'
import {logger} from 'redux-logger'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'

export const store = createStore(rootReducer , defaultState , applyMiddleware(thunk,logger) )
```

But I keep getting this error in the browser no matter what the middleware I use is:

[image]
And the page stops rendering!!

and it only works when I remove all the middleware from applyMiddleware, like this:

```
export const store = createStore(rootReducer , defaultState , applyMiddleware() )
```

P.S. I'm using the following libraries versions:

```
"react": "^15.2.1",
"react-dom": "^15.2.1",
"react-redux": "^4.4.1",
"redux": "^3.5.2",
"redux-thunk": "^2.1.0"
```

What can the problem be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated, based on your comment below. Try:

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';

const logger = createLogger();

createStore(rootReducer , defaultState , applyMiddleware(thunk,logger)
```

It's highly recommended that you refer to the documentation for the libraries you are using.

- [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)
- [redux-logger](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-logger)

Comment: Where is logger coming from?

Comment: only this works`export const store = createStore(rootReducer , defaultState , applyMiddleware() )
`

Comment: Yep, checked it, the problem is not in the middleware library I use, because I tried to use thunk only, logger only, a custom middleware only, and all of them fail with the same error posted

Comment: I think was following and old post. My mistake